# Changing a call to a JSON object to make program more abstract

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance

I have a program that builds a number of divs via data in a JSON file.  I call the info in the program like so:

```
'<p>English test score = ' + division[i].Eng5Thirteen +'</p>'
```

where Eng is the subject, 5 is the grade and Thirteen is the year (2013). I do a variation of this a ton of times.

Is there a way to update this program next year by just changing a variable that stores the word 'Thirteen' to 'Fourteen' and it will reflect through my whole program so I don't have to change it all next year? Maybe my whole program is inefficient?

You can see the code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Jonnyd55/6310282) and the running program [here.](http://bl.ocks.org/Jonnyd55/raw/6310282/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference the property via variables by using bracket notation, like this::

```
var subject="Eng", grade="5", year="Thirteen";
'<p>English test score = ' + division[i][subject+grade+year] + '</p>';
```